# How can I get one excel cells value to stay one step behind a change in another cell?

Tags: excel, vba, variables, variant

*Introduction:*
Thank you for taking your time to read this to help me and teach me. I am new to Stack Overflow and would appreciate any and all constructive criticism. I am open minded and happy to learn. Please be open and honest with your response. I am new to VBA, and self aught. I apologize for any misunderstandings in my explanation below and would be happy to clarify anything.

I will start with an explanation of the function of the worksheet.

*Purpose:*
This excel worksheet is meant to track dates of inventory changes. A document is received weekly that displays inventory changes I need to track. The worksheet needs to track two dates.

1. Date of the inventory being updated (usually is weekly, but that can vary)
2. Date of when inventory is ordered

*Example:*
Below is an example of the worksheet layout:

```
#########################
Sheet 1:
| Stock    | Previous |
| -------- | -------- |
| 200      | 200      |
| 100      | 100      |
#########################

##################################
Sheet 2:
| Stock    | Ordered  | Updated |
| -------- | -------- | ------- |
| 200      |    -     |   -     |
| 100      |    -     |   -     |
##################################
```

Sheet 1 purpose: Enter input into the "stock" column and perform the calculations
Sheet 2 purpose: Show the user all of the information including, stock amounts, and dates.

*How it works:*
In **Sheet 1** the user enters the stock into the "Stock" column in the respective row. The "Previous" column is there for the math that happens later. **Sheet 2** is locked. Nothing should be edited on this sheet. The purpose is to show all the information to the user. When The column "Stock" on **Sheet1** is updated, the column "Updated" on **Sheet2** should change to the current date. When the stock value drops below 150, the corresponding cell on **Sheet1** in the "Stock" column highlights red alerting the user that more stock needs to be ordered. When the stock value increases by more than 50 the date in the "Ordered" column should be updated to the current date.

*How I am doing it:*
Below I have included the code for the Workbook. All of the VBA code is inside of the Sheet1 module. I have one formula in **Sheet2** and it is in the "Stock" column in **Sheet2**. The purpose being to prevent the numbers from being updated if the user "clears contents" from the "Stock" column in **Sheet1**. Here is that formula:

***Sheet2** "Stock" column formula:*
=IF(OR(Sheet1!A2=0,Sheet1!A2=""),A2,Sheet1!A2)

*Sheet1 VBA Code:*

```
Public activeCellValue As Variant
Public activeCellAddress As Variant

 

Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sheet1 As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    activeCellValue = Target.Value
    activeCellAddress = Target.Address
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

'Setting Variables
Dim CardStockRange As Range
Dim userSelection As Range
Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
Dim destinationSheet As Worksheet

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'CardStock
'Assigning Values
Set CardStockRange = Range("A2:A62")
Set userSelection = Selection
Set sourceSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set destinationSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

'Copying the active cell address from Sheet1 sheet
activeCellAddress = Target.Address
activeCellValue = Target.Value

'Check if the selection is in the correct column
If Not Intersect(CardStockRange, userSelection) Is Nothing Then

    'Disable looping
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    'Difference variable is initialized to find difference between selection in A and B. If the
            'difference is higher than 50 update the date on Sheet2 page. If not then ignore.
        Dim difference As Variant
        'Math for difference variable
        difference = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value - activeCellValue

        'checking result
        If ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value < 150 And activeCellValue >= 150 And difference >= 50 Then

            'change to Sheet2 page, keeping the cursor on the same location of the selection from
                'Sheet1 page, move right one, add current date then move back to Sheet1 page.

            '''''''''''''''''''''''''''
            Sheets("Sheet2").Select
            Sheets("Sheet2").Range(activeCellAddress).Select
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "Order"
            Sheets("Sheet1").Select
            '''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        End If
Else
    'Do nothing
End If

'Re-enable loops
Application.EnableEvents = True

'Logic Test to see if the selection is in column for Stock
If Intersect(CardStockRange, userSelection) Is Nothing Then
    'DO nothing
Else
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Sheets("Sheet2").Range(activeCellAddress).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value = Date
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select

    'Paste the number from Column A
    ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Select
    ActiveCell.Value = activeCellValue
End If
End Sub
```

My issue is with comparing the values in the column A/Stock of **Sheet1** and column B/Previous of **Sheet1**. I need the "Previous" column to be one value change behind the user input from the "Stock" column of **Sheet1**.

*Example:*

```
Change 1
#########################
Sheet 1:
| Stock    | Previous |
| -------- | -------- |
| 200      | 0        |
| 100      | 0        |
#########################
Change 2
#########################
Sheet 1:
| Stock    | Previous |
| -------- | -------- |
| 100      | 200      |
| 600      | 100      |
#########################
Change 3
#########################
Sheet 1:
| Stock    | Previous |
| -------- | -------- |
| 700      | 100      |
| 300      | 600      |
#########################
Change 4
#########################
Sheet 1:
| Stock    | Previous |
| -------- | -------- |
| 250      | 700      |
| 425      | 300      |
#########################
```

This way I can calculate the difference between the two numbers and add the order date when the stock is increased by at least 50.

*The code that is having issues:*

```
If Not Intersect(CardStockRange, userSelection) Is Nothing Then

'Disable looping
Application.EnableEvents = False

'Difference variable is initialized to find difference between selection in A and B. If the
        'difference is higher than 50 update the date on Sheet2 page. If not then ignore.
    Dim difference As Variant
    'Math for difference variable
    difference = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value - activeCellValue

    'checking result
    If ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value < 150 And activeCellValue >= 150 And difference >= 50 Then

        'change to Sheet2 page, keeping the cursor on the same location of the selection from
            'Go to Sheet2 page, move right one, add current date then move back to Sheet1 page.

        '''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        Sheets("Sheet2").Select
        Sheets("Sheet2").Range(activeCellAddress).Select
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "Order"
        Sheets("Sheet1").Select
        '''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    End If
Else 
 'Do nothing
End If
```

*My issue:*
My problem arrises when I try to save the previous user input for the "Stock" column in **Sheet1** and offset it by one change. I know I could easily do this in python, but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to do it with VBA. I tried saving the value before it is changed, then comparing the value after the user hits enter, but that didn't work. So then I tried pasting the value in another cell, at the end of the program before the user hits enter so that the previous value and current value are compared, but Excel is just comparing the currently edited value. So if the user is entering 100, the program doesn't user the previous value, it is using the 100 that is currently being entered.

If I change A2 to 140 it is below the 150 threshold but it doesn't run the if statement. If I then lower the amount again by any amount   it runs the if statement. If I then increase the amount by more than 50 the order date changes.

I need it to be where if I lower the amount to 149 or lower and then increase it it changes. Currently I need to lower the amount below 150 twice for the if statement to run.

*Conclusion:*
I hope this makes senes. I look forward to all help, advice, constructive criticism, and teaching moments you will provide.

Thank you!

Comment: I have a feeling this is more an x y problem than anything. You mentioned you tried something that didn't work. Could you remove the unnecessary information and focus on that?

Comment: I sure can! I'll add a new code block specifically focusing on my issue.

Answer (score 0):

try

example using public variable to store the old value of column A in a worksheet selection change event , then in a worksheet change event show the old value into column B

```
Option Explicit
Dim oldvalue


Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Cells.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A:A")) Is Nothing Then
        Me.Range("B" & Target.Row) = oldvalue
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    oldvalue = Me.Range("A" & Target.Row)
End Sub
```